# Interact with []struct in golang

Tags: json, go

I have the code below:

```
type AzStorageAccount struct {
Type     string `json:"type"`
Location string `json:"location"`
Tags     struct {
} `json:"tags"`
Properties struct {
    PrivateLinkServiceConnections []struct {
        Name       string `json:"name"`
        Properties struct {
            PrivateLinkServiceID              string `json:"privateLinkServiceId"`
            GroupIds                          string `json:"groupIds"`
            PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState struct {
                Status          string `json:"status"`
                Description     string `json:"description"`
                ActionsRequired string `json:"actionsRequired"`
            } `json:"privateLinkServiceConnectionState"`
        } `json:"properties"`
    } `json:"privateLinkServiceConnections"`
    ManualPrivateLinkServiceConnections []interface{} `json:"manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections"`
    Subnet                              struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    } `json:"subnet"`
    CustomDNSConfigs []interface{} `json:"customDnsConfigs"`
} `json:"properties"`
```

}

But I'm having issues to assung the values to the variables inside  PrivateLinkServiceConnections []struct {}

At first I was using, but since I need to use []struct it does not work anymore.

```
storageAccount.Location = "eastus2"
    storageAccount.Type = "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints"
    storageAccount.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnections.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceId = "/subscriptions"
    storageAccount.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnections.Name = "priv-endpoint"
    storageAccount.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnections.Properties.GroupIds = "postgresqlServer"
    storageAccount.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnections.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState.Status = "Approved"
    storageAccount.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnections.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState.Description = "Auto-approved"
    storageAccount.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnections.Properties.PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState.ActionsRequired = "None"
    storageAccount.Properties.Subnet.Id = "/subscriptions/..."

marshaledStorageAccount, _ := json.Marshal(storageAccount)
utils.SendPut(endpoint, marshaledStorageAccount)
```

How can assign values to the code below?

```
PrivateLinkServiceConnections []struct {
        Name       string `json:"name"`
        Properties struct {
            PrivateLinkServiceID              string `json:"privateLinkServiceId"`
            GroupIds                          string `json:"groupIds"`
            PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState struct {
                Status          string `json:"status"`
                Description     string `json:"description"`
                ActionsRequired string `json:"actionsRequired"`
            } `json:"privateLinkServiceConnectionState"`
        } `json:"properties"`
    } `json:"privateLinkServiceConnections"`
```

Thanks!

Comment: `How can assign values to the code below?` Dont. I would not. This is too much of spaghetti type definition.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and sane way to do this is by defining a new type:

```
type PrivateLinkServiceConnections struct {
        Name       string `json:"name"`
       ...   
}

Properties struct {
    Connections []PrivateLinkServiceConnections  `json:"privateLinkServiceConnections"`
    ...
```

Otherwise, you have to explicitly specify the structure of each struct every time you initialize an instance, like:

```
x:=struct {
        Name       string `json:"name"`
        Properties struct {
            PrivateLinkServiceID              string `json:"privateLinkServiceId"`
            GroupIds                          string `json:"groupIds"`
            PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState struct {
                Status          string `json:"status"`
                Description     string `json:"description"`
                ActionsRequired string `json:"actionsRequired"`
            } `json:"privateLinkServiceConnectionState"`
        } `json:"properties"`
    }{ 
     Name:"name",
     Properties:struct {
            PrivateLinkServiceID              string `json:"privateLinkServiceId"`
            GroupIds                          string `json:"groupIds"`
            PrivateLinkServiceConnectionState struct {
                Status          string `json:"status"`
                Description     string `json:"description"`
                ActionsRequired string `json:"actionsRequired"`
            } `json:"privateLinkServiceConnectionState"`
        } { 
       PrivateLinkServiceID: id,
     },
 }

storageAccount.PrivateLinkServiceconnections=append(storageAccount.PrivateLinkServiceConnections, x)
...
```

Comment: If make it simplier for sure, but still not sure how to add the values from PrivateLinkServiceConnections type in AzStorageAccount type before I do `marshaledStorageAccount, _ := json.Marshal(storageAccount)`

Tried differente ways but it did not work :(

Comment: You can add values to that as I showed above, with the `append`. The problem here is that you are using an unnamed type, so you have to repeat the whole struct every time you define an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

`PrivateLinkServiceConnections` is defined as an array. You cannot access it as you do with objects. To add items to it, you need to use `append`  function.

Also, you have defined it as an inline anonymous struct, hence your code has become messy. Define a specific type for PrivateLinkServiceConnections and then each time on append, simply assign it without the need to redeclare it. It is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

At first I did a workaround to add "[]" that I needed and it worked but it was not great.

But now I finally undertood how to it

#models file

```
type AccessPolicieS struct {
TenantID string `json:"tenantId"`
ObjectID string `json:"objectId"`
Permissions struct {
    Keys         []string `json:"keys"`
    Secrets      []string `json:"secrets"`
    Certificates []string `json:"certificates"`
    } `json:"permissions"`
}

    type AzVaultPriv struct {
    Properties struct {
        AccessPolicies []AccessPolicieS
    } `json:"properties"`
}


acessP := models.AccessPolicieS{}
    acessP.TenantID  = "*******"
    acessP.Permissions.Keys = append(acessP.Permissions.Keys, "UnwrapKey")
    acessP.Permissions.Keys = append(acessP.Permissions.Keys, "WrapKey")
    acessP.Permissions.Keys = append(acessP.Permissions.Keys, "Get")
    acessP.Permissions.Secrets = append(acessP.Permissions.Secrets, "get")
    acessP.Permissions.Certificates = 
    append(acessP.Permissions.Certificates, "get")

    newModel := models.AzVaultPriv {}
    newModel.Properties.AccessPolicies = append(newModel.Properties.AccessPolicies, acessP)
    marshaledObject, _ := json.Marshal(newModel)
```

Follow below a work around that's not ideal, but kept me going foward until I fixed this.

```
func FormatJsonStructVaultPriv(json []byte) []byte {
    json = bytes.Replace(json, []byte("Policies\":{"), []byte("Policies\":[{"), 1)
    json = bytes.Replace(json, []byte("get\"]}}}}"), []byte("get\"]}}]}}"), 1)
    return json
}
```

Thanks for the help!